# Prevent Wicket 8 AjaxEventBehavior onChange to NOT SUBMIT forms on child pages

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, java-ee-8

I`m using Wicket 8 and i have a big problem:

I Have an abstract BasePage, (HomePage extends BasePage) and (LoginPage extends BasePage)

I am using BasePage to add a navigation bar to all pages on which there is a DropDownChoice to change the language.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public BasePage(PageParameters params){
        super(params);
        initPage();
    }

private void initPage(){
    createLocalesDCC();
    createHeaderLinks();
}

private void createLocalesDCC() {
    List<Locale> locales = Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH, new Locale("ru"));
    final DropDownChoice<Locale> localeDDCSelection = new DropDownChoice<Locale>("changeLocale",
            new Model<Locale>(), locales, getLocalesChoiseRenderer());
    localeDDCSelection.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            Session.get().setLocale(localeDDCSelection.getModelObject());
            target.add(getPage());
            System.out.println(getPage().getPageClass());
        }
    });
    localeDDCSelection.add(new AjaxPreventSubmitBehavior());
    localeDDCSelection.setModelObject(Session.get().getLocale());
    add(localeDDCSelection);
}
```

When localeDDC is rendering it is setting ModelObject of current language and displaying it.
When i changing language - it will re-render whole page (using selected language)

Also i have HomePage

```
public HomePage() {
    getTitle().setDefaultModel(Model.of("Home Page"));
}
```

Nothing intresting here, it's just an empty page for now. The DropDownChoice with ajax is working perfectly!

And here is the full code of my LoginPage:

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel;
RequiredTextField<String> userNameField;
PasswordTextField passwordTextField;
Button submitBtn;

public LoginPage(PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    if (((AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).isSignedIn()) {
        continueToOriginalDestination();
    }
    add(getLoginForm("loginForm"));
}

private Form getLoginForm(String id) {
    Form form = new Form(id);

    feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
    userNameField = new RequiredTextField<String>("username");
    passwordTextField = new PasswordTextField("password");
    submitBtn = new Button("submitBtn") {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
            AuthenticatedWebSession session = AuthenticatedWebSession.get();
            if (session.signIn(userNameField.getModelObject(), passwordTextField.getModelObject())) {
                setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
            } else {
                error("Login failed");
            }
        }
    };
    form.add(feedbackPanel, userNameField, passwordTextField, submitBtn);

    return form;
}
```

On this Page i also have top nav bar with language DropDown (same as in HomePage)
But the DropDownChoice with ajax is not working as i want, because when i change the language, it is **submitting** the loginForm and trying to authenticate in onSumbit() of this form, and it's called before AjaxEventBehavior for localesDropDownChoice, so nothing happens and there is error occured, because it is sending empty field (username and password) and trying to login.

How to prevent AjaxEvent on DropDownChoise to NOT submit the loginForm on extended Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a Solution:
I`m Using Spring Security, so any post action on LoginPage is proceed by SpringSecurity, so i removed this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    filter.setForceEncoding(true);
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, CsrfFilter.class);
    http.csrf().disable();

  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/adminpanel/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/cabinet").access("hasRole('USER')or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    /*removeed*///.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```